# I get a syntax error when I try to send a discord message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I cannot run the program and I just get a syntax error. I am trying to send a message to a specific channel, but the ch variable for some reason lights up red. I am new to this, and I am not very good.

```
ch = client.get_channel(12345642256905728)
await ch.send('hello')
```

Comment: can you post the full traceback please? its hard to help without it

Comment: It does not even run. It just gives me a "invalid syntax" and the ch lights up red

Comment: it must be giving you a traceback if it isn't running, you even said it tells you "invalid syntax". i don't know much about discord's api, but I assume you're using discord.py?

maybe you can try client.get_channel('12345642256905728')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use "await", you have to use it inside of an asynchronous function. So you could so something like this:

```
async def sendMessage(message):
    ch = client.get_channel(12345642256905728)
    await ch.send(str(message))
```

The "str(message)" is just a safety precaution since you need to send a string when using ch.send().

Answer (score 1):

await has to be called from a function. If you are not calling await from within a function you will get error as below:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> await asyncio.sleep(1)
File "<stdin>", line 1
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Ah errors, what will we do without your undescriptiveness and general terribleness? Oh, I know: streamline the programming process

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Your perfix', description="Your description")

# You need to do @bot.command() because you have the bot = commands.Bot if you don't like it you can change it to client
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    # Ctx stands for context and where the message came from
    ctx.channel.send("What you want the bot to send after you did your prefix command")
    # For example if your bots prefix is ! you need to do !test for it
```